# Moving from lerna to pnpm

Tags: javascript, npm, lerna, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I am currently migrating our project from Lerna to PNPM and we have a script we run I have posted it below

```
"postinstall": "npm run bootstrap"
"bootstrap": "lerna bootstrap --hoist",
"clean": "lerna clean -y",
```

is there a PNPM equivalent of Lerna bootstrap command and Lerna clean command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any Lerna bootstrap equivalent, just get started with pnpm workspace is easy enough, you just need to add a `pnpm-workspace.yaml` file in your project root and add the location of your packages (which is typically `packages/`). As mentioned on pnpm [documentation](https://pnpm.io/workspaces):

> A workspace must have a `pnpm-workspace.yaml` file in its root. A workspace also may have an `.npmrc` in its root.

Hoisting is not recommended with pnpm and is disabled by default, but if you really want to hoist then you can add `shamefully-hoist` into `.npmrc`, see pnpm [doc - shamefully-hoist](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#shamefully-hoist)

> By default, pnpm creates a semistrict `node_modules`, meaning dependencies have access to undeclared dependencies but modules outside of `node_modules` do not. With this layout, most of the packages in the ecosystem work with no issues. However, if some tooling only works when the hoisted dependencies are in the root of `node_modules`, you can set this to `true` to hoist them for you.

I'm not sure about `lerna clean` equivalent but to remove a dependency from node module, you can use `pnpm remove --recursive` as per pnpm [doc - remove](https://pnpm.io/cli/remove)

> When used inside a workspace (with `--recursive`), removes a dependency (or dependencies) from every workspace package.

> When used not inside a workspace, removes a dependency (or dependencies) from every package found in subdirectories.

You can see an example of all of that in Lerna-Lite [pnpm-workspace.yaml](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite/blob/main/pnpm-workspace.yaml) and I would suggest you to take a look at [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite) and maybe not give up Lerna entirely, I created Lerna-Lite fork when Lerna was no longer maintained (it is now) and the big difference is that Lerna-Lite only has a subset of the original Lerna commands (all the Lerna commands you mentioned aren't in Lerna-Lite because all package managers now handle these better than Lerna/Lerna-Lite does), the other distinction is that it's much smaller since I also made a few commands as optional packages and only kept `version` and `publish` in the core CLI, so it's much smaller when `version` and `publish` is all you need. I also don't like the new Lerna changes and the new direction that Lerna is now heading to (it's becoming more & more another Nrwl/Nx product, because Lerna v6 is now requiring Nx behind the scene, and that is not the case with Lerna-Lite, Nx can be installed with Lerna-Lite but it's totally optional and that's the way it should and will always be in Lerna-Lite).